# How does the NewRelic agent work on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, newrelic

How does the NewRelic agent know how many instances are running or how much RAM the app is using?

I'm wondering how it can glean so much without running an agent on the system as I thought you could only run your application code on Heroku, and not just any process?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're referring to Ruby, but the agent is not actually different on Heroku except for some accounting integrations due to New Relic/Heroku partnerships.

If you're using the New Relic Add-On for Heroku, the memory usage displayed in the "Instances" tab is an average per process.

New Relic will only track the instances that are being used by the app in the time window that you select.

Comment: But how does it get the mem usage for the process? And what happens if you use a forking app server like Unicorn?